# Unable to find control with path when using model and formgroupdirective

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

My Angular 8 app uses a lot of nested forms and in an attempt to minimise the amount of code, I set up a model class to define a structure for my reactive forms.  My html page has an accordion of nested components which is supposed to create a form to add or update data.  When trying to populate my form with existing data based on the model structure, I now get an error that says (example): ERROR Error: Cannot find control with path: 'info -> charName'

In my **home.ts**, I import the exported classes and I create the parent form like this:

```
this.CharGenMagusForm = this.fb.group({
  characterid: [''],
  playerUID: [''],
  covenantID: [''],
  info: this.fb.group(new Info()),
  infoMagus: this.fb.group(new InfoMagus),
  characteristics: this.fb.group(new Characteristics()),
  abilities: this.fb.group(new Abilities()),
  arts: this.fb.group(new Arts()),
  armour: this.fb.group(new Armour()),
  agingWarping: this.fb.group(new AgingWarping()),
  chargen: this.fb.group(new Chargen()),
  playerChar: ['']
})
```

In my **home.html**, I add (example) the info component as follows:

```
<mat-expansion-panel>
        <mat-expansion-panel-header>
          <mat-panel-title><h3>CHARACTER INFO</h3></mat-panel-title>
        </mat-expansion-panel-header>
        <ng-template matExpansionPanelContent>
          <hr />
          <form [formGroup]="CharGenMagusForm">
            <app-info [parent]="CharGenMagusForm" (CloseThisPanel)="onClose($event)"></app-info>
          </form>             
        </ng-template>
      </mat-expansion-panel>
```

In **info.ts**, I have the following:

```
  @Input() parent: FormGroup;
  @Output() CloseThisPanel = new EventEmitter<any>();

  infoData: Observable<Info>;
  fgd: FormGroupDirective;
  info: FormGroup;

constructor(private characterDetailsService: CharacterDetailsService, private fb: FormBuilder, parent: FormGroupDirective) {
    this.fgd = parent;
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.info = this.fgd.form;
    this.info.addControl('info', this.fb.group(new Info()));
    this.infoData = this.characterDetailsService.GetCharacterInfo().pipe(
      tap(infoData => this.parent.patchValue({info: infoData}))        <-------I suspect the problem lies here???
    );
  }
```

and in the **info.html** I have:

```
<div [formGroup] = "parent">
  <form *ngIf="infoData | async"  formGroupName="info">

<---and all the form control stuff--->
```

**CharacterDetailsService** gets all the data from Firestore with the specific function for info.ts as:

```
GetCharacterInfo() {
  return of<Info>(this.characterInfoData);
}
```

The **Info** model class:

```
export class Info {
  public charName: string;
  public type: string;
  public covenant: string;
  public gender: string;
  public size: number;
  public bornYear: number;
  public currentYear: number;
  public charAge: number;
  public height: string;
  public weight: string;
  public hair: string;
  public eyes: string;
  public charPic: string;
  public charPicDataUrl: string;
}
```

I'd appreciate some help on where I am going wrong.

Comment: Hmmm, when using {{info.value | json}} it seems like it is displaying the parent form structure (which contains info) and not the info form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is with this line:

```
info: this.fb.group(new Info())
```

At runtime this will be equal to this:

```
info: this.fb.group({})
```

so you basically adding a group with no nested controls (charName doesn't exist). this is because your class doesn't provide a default value for the properties, you can fix it by changing the class to be like this

```
export class Info {
  public charName: string = '';
  public type: string  = '';
  public covenant: string  = '';
...
```